# Where can I read Bleach legally?

Tags: bleach, europe

I live in Norway. Is there a site where I can read *Bleach* online legally? I have tried to look, but I have not found a suitable site yet.

Comment: Take a look at this post. http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal/923#923

Comment: Check out this site.  I believe they sell electronic subscriptions to WSJ for about $25 per year.  http://shonenjump.viz.com/  They even sent me a promotional paper comic once.  I believe it had a chapter from Naruto gaiden.  For the record, I live in the US, but It's online, so It might be available in norway too

Comment: you might find this post useful: http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/25961/6481

Comment: Do you know where  I can read the latest chapters online? Yes the latest chapters, I cannot seem to get WSJ subscribtion here(after my attempts)

Answer (score 1):

You can buy digital version of Bleach on a per-volume basis.

According to Viz Media's site, digital versions should be avaible from:

- Amazon
- Google Play
- Nook
- iBooks
- VizManga

I'm not sure about the region restrictions of these though, as you are living in Norway - Viz may not have the licensing rights for the regions (They usually prioritize the US first). You may have to import physical books if noone owns the licensing rights.

Comment: Do you know where  I can read the latest chapters online?

Comment: @rufaelJ.O I believe VizManga is an online reader